# Django- NoReverseMatch at /login/here/

Tags: python, django

I just don't understand. I've spent too much time on this error. Please help me pinpoint the issue. Let me know if you need any other information.

Error reads:
NoReverseMatch at /login/here/
Reverse for 'welcome' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

**Project urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',     admin.site.urls),
    # creating registered namespaces for each app
    url(r'^login/',     include('login_app.urls',   namespace = "login_app")),
]
```

**login_app/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'here/', views.login_user),
]
```

**login_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from login_app.forms import LoginForm

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response # this is going to be depricated
from django.template import RequestContext


def login_user(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    logout(request) # logs out user upon reaching the /login/ page
    user = password = ''
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.POST:
        # create a form instance and populate it with the data from the request:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            user = form.cleaned_data['user'] # extracting the username from the form before authenticating
            password = form.cleaned_data['password'] # extracting the password from the form before authenticating
            user = authenticate(username=user, password=password) # authenticating
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_app:welcome'))
                return HttpResponse("hi!")
            else:
               template = 'login.html'
               state = "Your username and/or password are incorrect."
               context = {'state': state,'form': form,}
               return render(request, template, context)
    template = 'login_app/login.html'
    state = ''
    context ={'state': state, 'form': form}
    #return HttpResponse("hey!")
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_app/css/login.css' %}">


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="well">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}<br>
        <!--error handling-->
        <p>{{ state }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**login_app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

## importing crispy form utilities
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Div, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions, PrependedText


class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    ## user field
    user = forms.CharField()

    ## password field
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )

    ## Using crispy forms to create a form
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.form_show_labels = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            PrependedText('user',       '<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>',     placeholder='Username'),
            PrependedText('password',   '<i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>',     placeholder='Password', autocomplete='off'),
            style='padding:0px;',
            css_class='col-md-3'
        ),
        Div(
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit','Login'), css_class='col-md-12'
            ),  css_class='row'
        )
    )
```

Comment: where are you calling the login page from that gives that error, it means you are giving it a parameter which the view is not expecting

Comment: `url(r'here/', views.login_user)` do not have name

Comment: see my answer.. try and let me know how it goes

Comment: I think maybe my view is passing two things, and the form is only expecting one? where does 'welcome' come from?

Comment: yes thats what im trying to figure out from your code

Comment: i dont mean the form i mean something like this <a href="{% url 'views.login_user' %}">Login</a>

Comment: where are you clicking in the template to give that error

Comment: i'm not clicking in a template. I'm just trying to render a page from a url. The view is where the issue is?

Comment: Where is this url pattern `dashboard_app:welcome`?

Comment: I'm not using it right now. I removed it to try to solve the issue. Was that a bad idea? I removed the app all together. It was confusing how I removed the app and yet it was appearing in the error.

Comment: i know you are trying to render a page but the page will only be visited through template. now u said u removed `dashboard_app: welcome`  from url. then check all ur template for where this `dashboard_app:welcome` occurs. django is still seeing this url in template

Comment: i'm checking. it's got to be here somewhere.

Comment: yeah do that i'm waiting

Comment: I just recursively searched the entire project. `grep -rnw 'CMIRSv1_0/' -e "dashboard_app:welcome"
CMIRSv1_0/login_app/views.py:41:                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_app:welcome'))` That was the only line it was found on. Maybe I should just start the project over?

Comment: can you do one thing create a respository in bitbucket or github so i can download and see for myself. dont start over, thats like running away from the problem which u might encounter again

Comment: it's looking for a phantom view...idk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104330/discussion-between-transformer-and-user1807271).

Answer (score 0):

So for future reference here's what happened....

The `base.html` (which I didn't post) had this line in it.

`<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Clinical Molecular Incident Reporting System</a> <!-- {% url 'login_app:welcome' %}-->`

The mistake here was I assumed the commenting out of html `<!---->` would also apply to Django's inline rendering syntax `{%%}`, but it didn't (Looking back on this, I have no idea why I thought that). Deleted the html comment and viola! I spend a lame forever amount of time solving this problem. Hopefully this will be of use to someone later.

Thanks to @Transformer for working to solve my issue.